# At what stage does SignalR automatically reconnect

Tags: javascript, signalr

I am just starting to learn/embrace SignalR.

I have this in my JavaScript page:

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      //Some Code
}).fail(function () {
     //Some Code
});
```

A connection is attempted to SignalR
The connection fails
Does it automatically try to reconnect until a connection is made or does it have to at least make a connection 1st before it tries to reconnect (whenever connection is lost).

Do I have to put a reattempt to connect in my .Fail function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime) around SignalR javascript clients. There is a section there called connection lifetime events. When a reconnect is happening SignalR raises an event, you can handle that event in your code. There are 7 connection events. In order for this to happen you need to make one successful connection. If the connection fails then you can add code as part of the fail function to retry

Comment: HI, thanks for your response and that link. I have read it before.  But it does not address my question. I am asking what happens if the initial connection is NOT made?  This document as far as I can see only addresses when a connection has already been made. But thanks for your time :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - Sorry did not see your final questions. Yes, you would need to add logic to attempt a reconnect.

Comment: Np. Glad I could help.